# Django-registration user_activated signal sent twice

Tags: python, django, django-registration, django-signals

I'm trying to receive the user_activated signal sent by django-registration when a user account is activated. Here is my signals.py

```
from registration.signals import user_activated

def receiver(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    print 'received signal'

user_activated.connect(receiver, dispatch_uid='registration.signals.user_activated')
```

But when a user is activated the user_activated signal is sent twice. I know this because the output is

```
received signal
received signal
```

Multiple imports of signals.py shouldn't connect the signal receiver twice because I use a unique dispatch_uid, so why is the signal sent twice? Is it a problem with my code or a problem with django-registration (using the default backend)?

Answer (score 1):

The `dispatch_uid` just stops you from connecting to the same signal twice, but the problem is that`django-registration` SENDS OUT the signal twice.

To fix it, apply [this](https://bitbucket.org/kami/django-registration/commits/6a0aff33bcf2cc24190916c74bc1b6822622d45a) patch to `registration/views.py` and it should work.